# Question posed in Spivak Chapter 14 that $f$ cannot be a derivative

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I'm having trouble working out the reasoning behind a question posed in Spivak's Calculus Chapter 14, where he discusses the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. The excerpt where this is from is as follows:

*... A function $f$ may be integrable without being the derivative of another function. For example, if $f(x) = 0$ for $x \ne 1$ and $f(1) = 1$, then $f$ is integrable, but $f$ cannot be a derivative (why not?)*

I tried working it out to verify whether $f$ is differentiable by using the definition of a derivative, but realised that the statement was that $f$ cannot **be** a derivative, not that $f$ is **not differentiable** (unless there's something I'm missing out here?). Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, the statement made is that $f$ cannot be a derivative. For the reason, look back to Chapter 11 (somewhere near theorem $7$ if I remember correctly), where Spivak explains why a derivative cannot have a jump discontinuity.

Actually if you look at the problems of chapter $11$, there's one (due to Darboux I think) which says that derivatives of functions satisfy the intermediate-value property (this is a much stronger assertion, but is not needed for this particular question).

Comment: Oh right! Yes, that theorem did exist. In hindsight, I was likely unable to appreciate that theorem prior to this example. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: @iobtl I recall that in Spivak's treatment this theorem is also used in Chapter 15 on trigonometric functions to prove rigorously that $\sin' = \cos$ and $\cos' = - \sin$ (this theorem is needed because Spivak's definition of the trigonometric functions is done first only for $[0,\pi]$ and then extended to all of $\Bbb{R}$, so some care is needed in treating these endpoints)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $g'(x)=f(x).$  Since $g'(x)=0$ for $x<1$, we have $g(x)=c_1$ if $x<1$ for some constant $c_1$.  Similarly, $g(x)=c_2$ if $x>1$ for some constant $c_2$.  Now either $c_1=c_2$ and $f(1)=g'(1)=0$ or $c_1\neq c_2$ and $g'(1)$ does not exist.

In general, a derivative has no jump discontinuity.

Comment: This is a nice example, thank you!

Comment: "In general" if the function whose derivative we are computing is continuous, right? We can have a function $f$ that isn't continuous at certain points. $f'$ would not be defined at those points, and could have jump discontinuities at those points. Is this correct?

Comment: @evianpring If the derivative doesn't exist at that point, it doesn't have a discontinuity, it just doesn't exist.  Look at the accepted answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need Darboux's Theorem for this. Assume $f$ is defined on $(1-\delta,1+\delta)$ for some $\delta>0$ and that there is a function $F$ that satisfies $F'=f$. Then, if $x\neq 1,\ F=c$ for some constant $c$ (why?). Then, by continuity, $F(1)=c$, so in fact $F'(1)=0\neq 1=f(1)$ and we have a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Assume, for proof by contradiction, that there is a function $g$ such that $g'=f$.

Since $g$ is differentiable everywhere by assumption (since $f$ is defined everywhere), it must be continuous.

For any $x \in (1,\infty)$ or $x \in (\infty,1)$, we have $f(x)=g'(x)=0$. Thus, $g$ is constant on these intervals. Let's call the constant value $c_-$ on $(\infty,1)$ and $c_+$ on $(1,\infty)$.

It must be that $c_-=c_+$ since by continuity of $g$

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 1^+} g(x)= \lim\limits_{x\to 1^+} c_+ = g(1)$$
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-} g(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-} c_-=g(1)$$

$$\implies c_-=c_+=g(1)$$

But then $g$ is constant everywhere and $g'(1)=f(1)=0$, which is a contradiction since $f(1)=1$ by assumption.

Therefore, by proof by contradiction, there is no function $g$ such that $g'=f$. Ie, $f$ is not the derivative of any function.